# Import from local file to next.config.js

Tags: import, next.js, node-modules

This may be applicable to node modules in general, but I am experiencing this with `next.config.js` in my `Next.js` application.

When I try to import from a local file in `next.config.js` like so:

```
const {I18N} = require('./utils/constants/i18n')
```

During build it throws an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './utils/constants/i18n'
```

The path is correct. Also, `npm intellisense` pluging in `VS Code` editor suggests/auto-completes this exact path.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does that happen when you simply run `next build` locally?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @artooras Any luck with this? I am running into the same issue as well

Comment: Unfortunately, no... I have however changed my `next.config.js` file since to not need to import from a local file.

Answer (score 2):

for anyone trying to figure this out, i think it fails cause there's no automatic extension discovery so the filename needs to be fully-qualify

```
const {I18N} = require('./utils/constants/i18n.ts')
```

however also be aware that the code you require has to support commonjs as well (ie. no `import`) or you won't be able to require it

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON to use the require method